# How to break a line much like <br /> or \n in embedded ruby within a Haml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, embedded-ruby

I am having trouble breaking a line in embedded ruby within a Haml file. I have the following code:

```
= "#{event.setup_time} Minute Setup" unless event.setup_time == nil
= "#{event.teardown_time} Minute Teardown" unless event.teardown_time == nil
```

But it is printing it all in one string. Any suggestions?
Cheers ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<br />` HTML tag like so:

```
= "#{event.setup_time} Minute Setup"       if event.setup_time.present?
%br/
= "#{event.teardown_time} Minute Teardown" if event.teardown_time.present?
```

If you want to avoid the `<br />` if unnecessary, this might be your solution instead:

```
- if event.setup_time.present?
  = "#{event.setup_time} Minute Setup"       
  %br/
- if event.teardown_time.present?
  = "#{event.teardown_time} Minute Teardown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
= "#{event.setup_time} Minute Setup" unless event.setup_time == nil
%br
= "#{event.teardown_time} Minute Teardown" unless event.teardown_time == nil
```

This will insert a `<br>` element between the two strings.

You can also do this:

```
%p
  = "#{event.setup_time} Minute Setup" unless event.setup_time == nil
%p
  = "#{event.teardown_time} Minute Teardown" unless event.teardown_time == nil
```

This will place the two strings within different `<p>` elements.